Finite-order automorphisms in the absolute Galois group of a $p$-adic field?
I'm searching for a sort of analogue of the complex conjugation.
More precisely, let $K$ be a characteristic zero field complete with respect to an ultrametric absolute value. Let $C$ be the completion of its algebraic closure and $$G:=\operatorname{Gal}^\text{cont}(C/K)$$
the group of continuous automorphisms of $C$ over $K$.
I would like to know if there are examples where both the following conditions are satisfied:

$C$ is not spherically complete

$G$ has a (non-trivial) finite subgroup .


I also do not have examples where $G$ has non trivial finite subgroups and $C$ is spherically complete.
Up to now, I was trying to use the explicit description of $G$ when $K=\mathbb{Q}_p$ given for instance in Theorem 7.5.14 of " Neukirch, Jürgen; Schmidt, Alexander; Wingberg, Kay (2000), Cohomology of Number Fields, Grundlehren der Mathematischen Wissenschaften, vol. 323, Berlin: Springer-Verlag, ISBN 978-3-540-66671-4, MR 1737196, Zbl 0948.11001 ", but I'm not able to extract information from that description.

I guess there's no such an example for $p$-adic case due to the Artin-Schrier theorem: if there's such an element $\sigma$, then its fixed field $C^\sigma$ is a finite index subfield of $C$, but then we should have $C^\sigma = C$ (I strongly believe that $C$ is not a real closed field because it is not an ordered field).

As Seewoo Lee points out, this is obstructed by the Artin–Schreier theorem.
Suppose that such $\sigma$ exists. By Artin–Schreier, it has order 2, and $C^\sigma \subset C$ is real-closed, and $C = C^\sigma[\sqrt{-1}]$. But $C^\sigma \supset \mathbb Q_p$. Can this happen?
When $p \equiv +1 \pmod 4$, $-1$ is a square in $\mathbb{F}_p$ and hence in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and hence in $\mathbb{Q}_p$. (Recall that when $p$ is odd, the squares in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ are precisely the numbers with square residue mod $p$; when $p=2$, you check mod $8$.) So $\sqrt{-1} \in C^\sigma$.
Suppose that $p=2$ or $p \equiv -1 \pmod 4$, so that $-1$ is not a square in $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Then, if $n$ is coprime to $p$, exactly one of $n$ and $-n$ is a square in $\mathbb{Q}_p$; notably, $p-1$ is not a square, whereas $-p+1$ is. In a real closed field, any sum of squares is again a square. So $p-1$ is a square in $C^\sigma$. But $-p+1$ is also a square in $C^\sigma$, and so $-1$ is a square in $C^\sigma$. But then $C^\sigma$ is not real-closed.

Thanks Seewoo Lee and Theo Johnson-Freyd ! I think this is ok
